# I have a few questions about foldleft in ATS

Tags: functional-programming, ats

I have an assignment that I have to do for school which involves using foldleft to find the length of a list. My question lies in the implementation of foldleft. We were given some example code that uses foldleft to multiply every item in a list by x.

```
implement
list0_mult(xs) =
list0_foldleft<int><int>(xs, 1, lam(res, x) => res*x)
```

In the third line, what does  mean? We have to get the length function to work with any datatype, and I'm assuming to do that I may need to change one or both of those.

Comment: I believe that you should consult your professor.

Comment: I think I figured it out, thank you

Comment: @JakeLipson: Then answer your own question with the answer for future reference :)

Answer (score 2):

I think I've figured out the answer to my own question:

The first  refers to the datatype that the foldleft is going to return, and the second  refers to the datatype that is in the list that the foldleft is dealing with. For foldright, the first and second 's swap locations.

Answer (score 2):

Your TA here.

`list0_foldleft` has the following definition. (You can find this in your assignment.)

```
extern fun {res:t@ype}{a:t@ype} list0_foldleft
  (xs: list0 a, ini: res, fopr: (res, a) -<cloref1> res): res
```

Here, `{res:t@ype}` is the first template argument representing the type of return value, and `{a:t@ype}` is the second template argument representing the type of the element of the list. For `fopr`, its type is `(res, a) -<cloref1> res`, which is a closure (function + environment) taking two arguments of type `res` and `a`, and return a value of type `res`.

In the call site,

```
list0_foldleft<int><int>(xs, 1, lam(res, x) => res*x)
```

the first `<int>` is indicating that return type `res` is `int`, and the second `<int>` is indicating that the type of list element is `int` (which is probably not what you want).

I believe you can figure out what goes wrong from here.

Comment: Thank you, I figured this out and tried to explain it in when I answered my own question but your explanation is much more elegant and readable.